# Onesignal wordpress notification get post data to android app

Tags: php, android, wordpress, onesignal

I am using onesignal notification plugin  wordpress  implemented in my android  app every thing works well The problem is that i want when user tap on the notification   i  want  to  get  the wordpress  site  post 's full content  data  (post title  +  post  description)  ...i  know  thas  json  return  push  content    "additional data" but  it  content  only  post  title  and  url  post (not  content  the  post full  data  like  description  and  the  writter) !

those  data  i  wil  explore  it  to  manipulate  the  post  detail  's  activity  (do  not  inclure  any  webview ! )

i  asked  the  onesignal  team  about  it  and  they  purposed  me  to  modify  the  plugin  php  code  directly  using  onesignal_send_notification_filter($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post)

i  need  a  help  to  solve  it

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onesignal_send_notification_filter()` is a [WordPress filter hook](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-actions-and-filters--wp-27373) that allows extending our plugin's behavior without modifying our plugin's code. [See this section of OneSignal's documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/guides-examples#customizing-wordpress-plugin-behavior) for more information, including beginning sample code.

Inside the callback, you have access to the $post object, which [comes with these fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post), including the `post_content` field.

Comment: Janson - I have same issue could you please let me know code.

Comment: In my case app open but not go to the particular article page. Here is my post . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49255275/onesignal-how-to-go-to-app-article-state-after-opening-notification-on-android